# What is the correct way of blacklist an api by api context?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to follow the tutorial in this link: [Link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Managing+Throttling)

But I keep getting this error

````
```
2019-11-26 15:50:46,954] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : blockingEventJMSPu
blisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.prop
erties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationTy
pe=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
````

Can you guys help me with that?

[UPDATE]

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Admin+App+Event+Publishing+for+Traffic+Manager+HA+Setup) and it stopped the errors but still doesn't work

Log File [Link](https://pastebin.com/f9gyF0fj)

Comment: You must have seen startup errors. For some reason, the JMS client is unable to connect to the topic.

Comment: Shows this error - "JMSListner Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start JMS provider now" how can I do this?

Comment: Please send your full startup log.

Comment: it's a long file so a posted on a link

Comment: Seems you're running with an offset of 3. Is this not a single node setup?

Comment: yes, I'm using offset because of the wso2ei that is running as well in the same machine, and I'm not sure what do you mean with your question, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: 1) How many APIM nodes do you have? 2) If you unzip and start a new APIM server, does that give you the same startup error?